# Unable to apply yum security updates

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rhel-7

I've a few FreeIPA servers that were built using the official CentOS repositories and EPEL repo for FreeIPA.

`[root@freeipa yum.repos.d]# cat /etc/redhat-release CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`

```
[root@freeipa yum.repos.d]# cat /etc/redhat-release CentOS Linux
release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

```
[root@freeipa yum.repos.d]# ipa --version 
VERSION: 4.5.4,
API_VERSION: 2.228
```

When I try to run a yum update --security I get:

```
 * base: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
 * epel: mirrors.syringanetworks.net
 --> libtevent-0.9.33-2.el7.x86_64 from @base removed (updateinfo)
 --> libsemanage-python-2.5-11.el7.x86_64 from @base removed (updateinfo)
 --> 1:perl-IO-Zlib-1.10-294.el7_6.noarch from base removed (updateinfo)
 --> sssd-proxy-1.16.4-21.el7.x86_64 from base removed (updateinfo)
 --> libcroco-0.6.8-5.el7.x86_64 from installed removed (updateinfo)
 --> 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-21.el7.x86_64 from base removed (updateinfo)
 --> initscripts-9.49.47-1.el7.x86_64 from base removed (updateinfo)
 --> kernel-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 from base removed (updateinfo)
 --> apr-1.4.8-5.el7.x86_64 from base removed (updateinfo)
 --> glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 from installed removed (updateinfo)
 --> libssh2-1.8.0-3.el7.x86_64 from base removed (updateinfo)
 --> python-urlgrabber-3.10-7.el7.noarch from installed removed (updateinfo)
 --> rdma-core-22.1-3.el7.i686 from base removed (updateinfo)
No packages needed for security; 340 packages available
Resolving Dependencies
```

But anyway I'm not being able to complete the update. I turned YUM to verbose (debuglevel=9) and now I also can see:

```
Not Updating Package that is already updated: lz4.x86_64 0:1.7.5-2.el7
Not Updating Package that is already updated: vim-enhanced.x86_64 2:7.4.160-4.el7
Not Updating Package that is already updated: libref_array.x86_64 0:0.1.5-25.el7
Not Updating Package that is already updated: libref_array.x86_64 0:0.1.5-25.el7
Not Updating Package that is already updated: selinux-policy.noarch 0:3.13.1-192.el7_5.3
Not Updating Package that is already updated: gssproxy.x86_64 0:0.7.0-17.el7
Not Updating Package that is already updated: iproute.x86_64 0:3.10.0-54.el7
Not Updating Package that is already updated: quota-nls.noarch 1:4.01-11.el7
```

```
[root@freeipa yum.repos.d]# yum repolist enabled
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
repo id                                   repo name                                                                  status
base/7/x86_64                             CentOS-7 - Base                                                            10,097
cr/7/x86_64                               CentOS-7 - cr                                                                   0
*epel/x86_64                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                             13,217
repolist: 23,314
```

I don't have any automatic update enabled.
Any idea how t solve this issue?